# multiply join in dynamic linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

im trying to join those tables i have to use dynamic linq,
   it`s working fine if  the **.Join(dbcontext.Providers)** has and returning data 
when i dont have data on the  **.Join(dbcontext.Providers)** the all **queryResolts** returnig 0 results

how can i get data even if one of the join returning 0 results

```
var queryResolts = dbcontext.Tracks
            // Add Services
            .Join(dbcontext.Services,
                track => track.ServiceId,
                service => service.ServiceId,
                (track, service) => new { Track = track, Service = service })
            // Add ServiceInterfaces
            .Join(dbcontext.ServiceInterfaces,
                ts => ts.Track.ServiceInterfaceId,
                serviceInterface => serviceInterface.ServiceInterfaceId,
                (ts, serviceInterface) => new { Track = ts.Track, Service = ts.Service, ServiceInterfaces = serviceInterface })
            // Add Providers
            .Join(dbcontext.Providers,
                tss => tss.Track.ProviderId,
                provider => provider.ProviderId,
                (tss, provider) => new { Track = tss.Track, Service = tss.Service, ServiceInterfaces = tss.ServiceInterfaces, Providers = provider })
            .Where("ServiceInterfaces.ServiceInterfaceName == @0", "PublishPolicyInterface2")
            .Select(y => y.Track) 

            ;
```

thanks

miki

Comment: It looks like two of the joins here are totally useless. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join` here works like `join` in `SQL`, it will not return any value if the joined table do not contain result.

if your need `left or right outer join` then use `GroupJoin()`.